# Interbase IBConfig setting for Server_Priority_Class

Tags: interbase

In the OpGuide on page 61:

SERVER_PRIORITY_CLASS . Priority of the InterBase service on Windows server
platforms
  . The value 1 is low priority, 2 is high priority
  . Relevant only on Windows server platforms
  . Default is 1

In the IBConfig file distributed with Interbase:

```
#SERVER_PRIORITY_CLASS    1
## Platforms: Windows
## Priority of the InterBase service on Windows
## The value 1 is low priority, 2 is high priority.
## Relevant only on Windows NT/2000/XP.
```

Just need a clarification when it is appropriate to change the 
Server_Priority_Class from the default (1) to 2.

The comment in the IBConfig file makes it sound that the setting is only for 
Windows NT/2000/XP, where the OpGuide says it is relevant only on Windows 
server platforms. None of our servers use Windows NT/2000/WinXP (all are Window Server 2003, 2008, etc)

Thanks,
Tom Greenway

Answer (score 0):

It does have an effect on any Windows version. The language in the comment stems from the days when IB was still supported on Windows 95.

However, you usually should not change this. Let the OS set thread priority.